# Python: List comprehension, combining 2 lists into 1 with unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to create a list that contains only elements from the original list a that are not in list b.

I have tried using list comprehension, but don’t understand why the numbers in the new list are repeated three times.

```
a = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]

b = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15]

c = [x for x in a if x not in b 
       for y in b if y not in a]
```

I expected this result:

```
[3, 9, 11, 14]
```

Comment: isn't `c = [x for x in a if x not in b]` sufficient?

Comment: `[x for x in a if x not in b]`

Comment: if an aswer helped you then please mark that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You added too much code

```py
a = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]
b = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15]

c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

This gives the following result just as you wanted!!

```py
print(c)

# [3, 9, 11, 14]
```

## Why Repeated 3 times?

Well look at the orginal data again

```py
original = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]
# Index     0  1  2  3   4   5   6
#           ✓  x  x  ✓   ✓   ✓   x  

second = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15]
#         0  1  2   3   4   5
#         ✓  x  x   ✓   ✓   x
```

You get 4 unique numbers [3, 9, 11, 14] because there are 4 numbers in `original` that are not in the `second` list.

You get 3 repeated numbers because there are 3 numbers in `second` that are not in the `orginal` list.

### Testing

You can test this idea by expanding the lists

```py
original = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]
second = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15, 100, 200]

# print(c)
# [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14]
```

Now we have 5 unique values in the `second` list, so it's repeated 5 times now!

Comment: Excellent explanation! This also solves the mystery of the repeated numbers :)

Answer (score 3):

An easier way would be to use sets.

```py
set_a = set(a)
set_b = set(b)

c = list(set_a - set_b) #Using set operator difference
c.sort() #If you need to have it in order
```

[Set Operator Difference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-operations-union-intersection-difference-symmetric-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
[*filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to preserve order then you can use `set.difference`

```
a = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]
b = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15]
c = set(a) - set(b)
```

Or if you want to use a comprehension:

```
c = [n for n in a if n not in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15]
b = [2, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15]
c = []

for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        c.append(i)
```